# Save condition for X candles with PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, forex, pine-script-v4

I'm looking for a way to "say" if condition is true since X candles = valid.

```
//@version=4
study("Hello","", true, max_labels_count = 100)

//EMA
smaSource = input(ohlc4, "Source")
smaInput = input(18, "Length")
ema1Source = input(close, "Source")
ema1Input = input(8, "Length")
ema2Source = input(close, "Source")
ema2Input = input(50, "Length")

sma = sma(smaSource, smaInput)
ema1 = ema(ema1Source, ema1Input)
ema2 = ema(ema2Source, ema2Input)

plot(sma, color=#FF7000, linewidth=1, title='SMA')
plot(ema1, color=#0088FA, linewidth=1, title='EMA #1')
plot(ema2, color=#FA00D0, linewidth=1, title='EMA #2')

longCondition = crossover(ema1, sma)
shortCondition = crossunder(ema1, sma)

trueLong = longCondition and close > ema2
trueShort = shortCondition and close < ema2

plotshape(trueLong, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green)
plotshape(trueShort, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red)
```

This is my current script and what I'm looking to do is this:

```
if longCondition and close > ema2
    plotshape(trueLong, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green)
```

But I want te longCondition to be true for X candles (I'll set the amount with input) so it should check if the longCondition was true in the last X candles and then if it's true + close > ema2 it should plot the shape

I figured out I could do this:

```
f_somethingHappened(_cond, _lookback) =>
    bool _crossed = false
    for i = 1 to _lookback
        if _cond[i]
            _crossed := true
    _crossed

// The function could be called multiple times on different conditions, that should reduce the code
trueLong = f_somethingHappened(longCondition, lookBack) and close > ema2
trueShort = f_somethingHappened(shortCondition, lookBack) and close < ema2
```

But now the next issue is that I only want it to print the first true signal af the crossover

Answer (score 2):

You could start counting the candles and only plot when the count =1

```
//Condition
ema5  = ta.ema(close, 5)
ema10 = ta.ema(close, 10)
var Condition = ta.crossover(ema5, ema10)

//Count
varv = 0                 // Declare the up counter
varv := nz(varv[1])   // Get the previous value of it
varv := Condition ? varv + 1 : 0    // Only increment the counter, if the condition is TRUE. Reset it otherwise
v = varv == 1   // Return *true* only on the first candle
```